# Created a python code using the bootstrap to generate html but unable to add colours to it

Tags: python, css, bootstrap-4

I have written the below code to generate html report but i am failing to make it look good likewise adding colours, making borders and alphabets bold etc.. i did try adding the tags like "table-bordered .table-dark" etc but nothing is happening. Not sure where I am going wrong. Can someone help me?

```py
    doc = dominate.document(title='###########')
        with doc.head:
            link(rel='stylesheet', href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css")
        with doc:
            with div(cls='container'):
                h1("Sjsdhsdss")
                with table(id='main', cls='table table-striped table-bordered .table-dark .table-hover'):
                    with thead(id='main', cls='thead-dark'):
                        with tr():
                            th("Host")
                            th("Status")
                            th("Reason")
                        with tbody():
                            for i in server_list:
                                for j in iwfhjcn:
                                    if re.search(i, j[0]):
                                        with tr():
                                            td(j[0])
                                            td(j[1])
                                            td(j[2])
```

Comment: Hello, you seem to be using Bootstrap 3.4 but the `table-dark` class is part of Bootstrap 4.  You might want to switch to the newer Bootstrap or add custom css to change the colors.

Comment: I changed the bootstrap to 4.6 and it worked fine. Thank you @solarc

Comment: How will I add a background colour to my code above? I am doing it this way            with div(cls='col-md-6',style='background-color: blue') but it is applying colour only to certain part of the page and not the whole page. how will I do it?